# Extrapolate confidence band around regression in R

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

I am trying to calculate a confidence band around a linear regression in R. I know that `predict` can do that in most cases, but I want an equation-based solution; partly because not all regression models (e.g. from the `deming` package) are compatible with `predict`, and partly because I want to understand it (hence also no `ggplot`-solution or alike).

I have come rather far, using the equations explained [here](https://stattrek.com/regression/slope-confidence-interval.aspx) and [here](https://library2.lincoln.ac.nz/documents/Analysing-the-Variance.pdf).

**What I have accomplished:**
I successfully calculate the *t*-value, the MSE and the standard error of the regression. I am very confident that all the equations in my implementation are correct to a large degree, because when I use them for the range of *x*-values the regression-model was calculated on, they perfectly fit what `predict` returns (see left plot in code).

**Where it gets complicated:**
The problems start when I try to extrapolate; or in other words when I want to calculate the confidence band beyond a range of *x*-values I have data for. The calculated confidence band is **still correct**, but it **is displaced**. Precisely, as you can see in the right plot below, you have to move the confidence band along the *x*-axis by the difference of the means of the original data and the data used for extrapolation. Likewise, on the *y*-axis the confidence band has to be displaced by the difference of the model for the respective means of the *x*-values. You see the calculations under the `#Define displacement vector` in the code below, if it is hard to understand.

I have a vague understanding why this displacement happens, given the equations for `se`. But I wonder if there is a better solution to the problem than the replacement of the confidence band I have implemented now (also because, due to the necessity to displace, my code now does not really calculate the confidence band across the intended interval). I would be very thankful if anyone could help me polish this code.

```
#Create data
Dat<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 2.1, 2.3, 2.2, 3.5, 3.1, 3.2, 4.2, 5.0, 4.8, 6.1, 6.6, 6.2), 12, 2))
colnames(Dat)<-c("X", "Y")

#Create linear model
mod<-lm(Y ~ X, data=Dat)

#Use predict to calculate confidence band for comparison
Pred<-predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(X=0:30), interval="confidence")

#Calculate confidence band according to equations
#https://stattrek.com/regression/slope-confidence-interval.aspx
#https://library2.lincoln.ac.nz/documents/Analysing-the-Variance.pdf
##Gather constants
n<-nrow(Dat)
##Define prediction values
Pred.vals<-list()
Pred.vals$S1<-seq(from=1, to=10, by=0.5)
Pred.vals$S2<-seq(from=0, to=30, by=0.5)
Pred.vals$S1.fitted<-coef(mod)[2]*Pred.vals$S1+coef(mod)[1]
Pred.vals$S2.fitted<-coef(mod)[2]*Pred.vals$S2+coef(mod)[1]
##Calculate t-value
t.val<-qt(p=1-((1-0.95)/2), df=n-2)
##Calculate MSE
mse<-sqrt(sum((Dat[,"Y"]-mod$fitted.values)^2)/(n-2))
##Calculate standard error of fit: two versions, both work, but se2 is displaced
se1<-mse*sqrt((1/n)+(Pred.vals$S1-mean(Pred.vals$S1))^2/sum((Dat[,"X"]-mean(Dat[,"X"]))^2))
se2<-mse*sqrt((1/n)+(Pred.vals$S2-mean(Pred.vals$S2))^2/sum((Dat[,"X"]-mean(Dat[,"X"]))^2))

#Define displacement vector
X.Mean<-list()
X.Mean$Original<-mean(Dat[,"X"])
X.Mean$New<-mean(Pred.vals$S2)
X.Mean$X.Diff<-X.Mean$Original-X.Mean$New
X.Mean$Y.Diff<-(coef(mod)[2]*X.Mean$Original+coef(mod)[1])-(coef(mod)[2]*X.Mean$New+coef(mod)[1])

#Calculate confidence band
slope.upper1<-Pred.vals$S1.fitted+t.val*se1
slope.lower1<-Pred.vals$S1.fitted-t.val*se1
slope.upper2<-Pred.vals$S2.fitted+t.val*se2
slope.lower2<-Pred.vals$S2.fitted-t.val*se2

#Plot and compare
win.graph(20, 10, 10)
layout(matrix(1:2, 1, 2))
##Small plot
plot(Dat[,"X"], Dat[,"Y"], xlim=c(0, 11), ylim=c(2, 7))
curve(coef(mod)[2]*x+coef(mod)[1], col="grey50", lwd=1, add=TRUE)
##Confidence interval from "predict"
lines(0:30, Pred[,"lwr"], col="cornflowerblue", lty=2)
lines(0:30, Pred[,"upr"], col="cornflowerblue", lty=2)
##Confidence intervals from equations
lines(Pred.vals$S1, slope.upper1, col="darkgreen", lwd=2, lty=2)
lines(Pred.vals$S1, slope.lower1, col="darkgreen", lwd=2, lty=2)
legend("topleft", col=c("grey50", "cornflowerblue", "darkgreen"), lwd=c(1, 1, 2), lty=c(1, 2, 2), legend=c("Regression line", "Confidence from 'predict'", "Confidence from equations"))

##Large plot
plot(Dat[,"X"], Dat[,"Y"], xlim=c(0, 30), ylim=c(2, 15))
curve(coef(mod)[2]*x+coef(mod)[1], col="grey50", lwd=1, add=TRUE)
##Confidence interval from "predict"
lines(0:30, Pred[,"lwr"], col="cornflowerblue", lty=2)
lines(0:30, Pred[,"upr"], col="cornflowerblue", lty=2)
##Confidence intervals from equations
#lines(Pred.vals$S1, slope.upper1, col="darkgreen", lwd=2, lty=2)
#lines(Pred.vals$S1, slope.lower1, col="darkgreen", lwd=2, lty=2)
lines(Pred.vals$S2, slope.upper2, col="firebrick", lty=3)
lines(Pred.vals$S2, slope.lower2, col="firebrick", lty=3)
lines(Pred.vals$S2+X.Mean$X.Diff, slope.upper2+X.Mean$Y.Diff, col="darkgreen", lwd=2, lty=3)
lines(Pred.vals$S2+X.Mean$X.Diff, slope.lower2+X.Mean$Y.Diff, col="darkgreen", lwd=2, lty=3)
legend("topleft", col=c("grey50", "cornflowerblue", "firebrick", "darkgreen"), lwd=c(1, 1, 1, 2), lty=c(1, 2, 3, 3), legend=c("Regression line", "Confidence from 'predict'", "Confidence from equations", "Confidence from equations (displaced)"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a very stupid mistake, but maybe it is still useful for someone. The only problem was, that for sure in the se calculation, the mean of the **orginal** *x*-data has to be used in the numerator as well.

```
se1<-mse*sqrt((1/n)+(Pred.vals$S1-mean(Dat[,"X"]))^2/sum((Dat[,"X"]-mean(Dat[,"X"]))^2))
se2<-mse*sqrt((1/n)+(Pred.vals$S2-mean(Dat[,"X"]))^2/sum((Dat[,"X"]-mean(Dat[,"X"]))^2))
```